# double-buffer from different class?

Tags: java

This in my class that is added to my JFrame. can anyone help me with how I can draw graphics from anouther class using this classes offScreen? for example have a Player class (Player.java) and draw an image and other things from that class but still buffer the image without making new double buffering methods in each class im drawing from?

```
package Display;

import Graphics.Player1;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
      import javax.swing.JPanel;



      public class DrawArea extends JPanel implements Runnable{      
    Thread drawLoop = new Thread(this);
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(1000, 700, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
   public Graphics offScreen = image.getGraphics();

    public DrawArea() {
        setSize(1000, 700);
        drawLoop.start();

    }

    public void update(Graphics g) {
        paint(g);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        offScreen.setColor(Color.yellow);
        offScreen.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 700);

        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            repaint();
            try {
                drawLoop.sleep(90);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DrawArea.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: if im am not detailed enough in my question please tell me because this has been irritating me for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

Make your DrawingPanel look like this.

```
public class DrawingPanel extends Canvas {

    public DrawingPanel(){
        setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

The main frame.

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements Runnable{

    DrawingPanel panel;

    public MyFrame(){
        panel = new DrawingPanel();
        add(panel);
        setVisible(true);
        panel.createBufferStrategy(2);
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public void run(){
        BufferStrategy buffer = panel.getBufferStrategy();
        while (true){
            Graphics g = buffer.getDrawGraphics();
            render(g);
            g.dispose();
            buffer.show();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(90);
            } catch (Exception e){}
        }
    }

    public void render(Graphics g){
        // Do your drawing here
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new MyFrame();
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you, have just read doc on Canvas, and just to be clear will everything drawn by this Graphics g will be buffered and any graphics objects from other classes? eg a draw method in anouther class draw(Graphics g) {g.fillrect.........}etc will be buffered

Comment: i am getting a exception when i try to run it with createBufferStrategy(2), "Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component must have a valid peer". will catching the exception be appropriate?

Comment: thanks, before that i had createBufferStrategy() in the update(graphics g). but drawing still "flickers" alot? any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

Create a Player class like this (you can even make an interface called Drawable with the paint method in it):

```
public class Player {

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        //Draw player specigfic things
    }
}
```

In your DrawArea add this to the paint method where the player is a Player object:

```
player.paint(g);
```

Comment: His main question is about double buffering.